# XCode 4.2: Renamed project file in project navigator, all project settings/config lost

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2

I'm panicking a bit here...

In the project navigator, I clicked and renamed my .xcodeproj file (thinking it was the way to rename the project).

What has happened is that all the settings and files for the project have disappeared from the project navigator, and i'm left with a blank project!

Checking in Finder, it's removed my old .xcodeproj file, created a new one with the name I gave it - but on inspection, the file is empty! nothing inside.

I fear I may have lost all the settings in there. My last commit to Git was a while back, so if I get it back from the repository, I will have lost some changes I made.

Is there a way to retrieve/undo what I have done, and restore my project?

See below - Alerts.xcodeproj is the "new" project I don't want.. no files associated with it at all.

[image]

(btw, somehow a while back I got my project file under a "New Group" - and I can't get that sorted either - but that could be a separate question!)

If I use the version editor, on the left pane I can see all the settings from the previously named project file.. but can't seem to get at them. I was expecting to see these on the right hand pane, actually - so I'm also confused by this. Can I use the version editor to get my old project file back somehow?

[image]

Many thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

OK so I renamed the project file in Finder back to my original project filename - which has resulted in my files etc being displayed in Xcode again.. phew! Well - almost!

I now have no schemes, as you can see below. Where are schemes stored? Do I need to rename a file to match the project file now?

[image]

**2nd Update - fixed it!**

It is not the nicest solution, but I have found a way to restore everything to it's original setting. I'm sure this is a convoluted way of doing it - so I will wait a while to see if anyone comes up with a better solution. If they don't, then I'll create and answer with the answer below:

In Finder, I renamed the project file back to what it was originally. This brought back files and settings when I launched XCode. However - no schemes!

I fixed this scheme problem by updating the project name within a couple of files. here is the procedure:

1. Right click on your project.xcodeproj file and select "Show Package Contents"
2. In the resulting folder, navigate down to the folder `xcuserdata/(username).xcuserdatad/xschemes/`
3. In here open up the .xscheme files, and find the following lines which will reference the old, unwanted & incorrect, project name:

> ReferencedContainer = "container:Alerts.xcodeproj"

(In my case, Alerts.xcodeproj was the incorrect project name)
   4. Change all occurences to match the correct project name.

Volia! fixes the problem.

Cheers :)

Comment: Glad you fixed your problem. I hope that you are now using version control!

Comment: @sosborn hehe, I was already, but will be committing a bit more often now!

Comment: An easier way to restore schemes is to just create a new one and it will get all of the schemes back to normal.  (Unless you had customized scheme settings, of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK this is not the nicest solution, but I have found a way to restore everything to it's original setting. I'm sure this is a convoluted way of doing it though!

In Finder, I renamed the project file back to what it was originally. This brought back files and settings when I launched XCode. However - no schemes!

I fixed this scheme problem by updating the project name within a couple of files. here is the procedure:

1. Right click on your project.xcodeproj file and select "Show Package Contents"
2. In the resulting folder, navigate down to the folder `xcuserdata/(username).xcuserdatad/xschemes/`
3. In here open up the .xscheme files, and find the following lines which will reference the old, unwanted & incorrect, project name:

> ReferencedContainer = "container:Alerts.xcodeproj"

(In my case, Alerts.xcodeproj was the incorrect project name)
   4. Change all occurences to match the correct project name.

Volia! fixes the problem.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Xcode does that if it thinks your project is open elsewhere.  It only allows a project to be open at one time. Close all your Xcode windows, and relaunch Xcode.  It should function like a normal project after that.

Comment: thanks - but on reloading, I still don't see anything in the project navigator :( the only difference seems to be that now in the version editor I have both left and right panes full of data.

Comment: Are you really opening up the right project? If so, drag the "Alerts.xcodeproj" out of the group you put it in.

Comment: Yes it's the right project. I've just updated the question as I've made some progress.. but now have no schemes :(