# iPhone: Changing XCode project name is safe?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I could change XCode project name with the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4954029/709950 .

Project file (.xcodeproj) and target name were changed.
But source folder name and scheme name doesn't changed.

I found the way to change scheme name by myself.
And I found the way to change source folder name on:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8344066/709950

Is it safe to change project name in the above way?
Are there anything I have to do to change project name completely?
Or is it safer and more clean to create new project and copy source files to it?

**EDIT:**
I found that committing of GIT of XCode doesn't work anymore after renaming project name.

And found a question about this problem:
[How do I rename an xcode scheme and keep Git commit working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933222/how-do-i-rename-an-xcode-scheme-and-keep-git-commit-working)

But the solution which is answered in that question is too complex for me to accept.

**EDIT2:**
I tried to re-create git repository after the above problem happened.
But I couldn't re-create. So I asked how to do it.
And I got a good answer.
[iPhone: How to re-create XCode built-in git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468041/iphone-how-to-re-create-xcode-built-in-git-repository)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanna change the application name, you just change the project name. All the rest is insignificant ( relax about the folder name and scheme ).

Comment: Thanks. I just wanna rename project name cleanly without a trace of the old project. App name can be renamed with `bundle display name` setting. I found new problem for renaming project name. I've added about this to my question. Committing GIT is not working after renaming project. Are you using GIT?

Comment: git committing problem solved. I added explanation and a link to the question.