# xcode project name

Tags: xcode

is it possible to change name of the whole project so, that I can make from it a different one.
I mean for example name is iPhone.xcodeproj, and I need a second one to try additional code on it for example with the name iPod.xcodeproj and also with all classes and frameworks and everything else.
So I need not only change the name of the file, I need to change the name of whole parts of project.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 1st copy the project folder
- 2nd rename the folder to what you want
- 3rd open the project in the new location
- 4th select your project

  [image]
- 5th rename your project to what you want
- 6th press enter and your're done...the project in the new location is renamed to what you want

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to copy project directory with Finder. (Don't rename project file).

And then maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453991/iphone-changing-xcode-project-name-is-safe) will help you.